# Not using route associated with source IP

Tags: linux, routing

My system is running armbian 11.6

It connects to the internet through wlan0, it works fine.
It also has an openvpn (tun0) connection.

I want to have all traffic routed routed through wlan0 except for a few programs that shall use tun0. VPN server runs fine, NAT is configured OK.

On my armbian system I have following routes:

```
default via 192.168.10.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp metric 600 
default via 10.8.0.1 dev tun0 metric 900 
10.8.0.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.52 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlan0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.10.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.10.100 metric 600
```

Now comes the issue running e.g. curl:
This works:

```
curl --interface tun0 https://api.ipify.org?format=json
```

This times out:

```
curl --interface 10.8.0.52 https://api.ipify.org?format=json
```

The interesting thing is: when running with the ip address and monitoring in parallel using tcpdump i see outbound packets with source IP 10.8.0.52 going out through wlan0. Obiously this is why it is failing.

The same behavior is observed with other apps where one is able to specify the source IP.

How can I solve this issue i.e. tell the system to use the adapter the IP belongs to ?

Another interesting behavior if i put wlan0 to a higher metric than tun0 I the issue occurs the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routing is (normally) on destination. To have several default routes with different metrics makes no sense. You must use source based policy routing.

```
ip ro del default via 10.8.0.1
ip rule add from 10.8.0.52/32 table 10
ip route add default via 10.8.0.1 table 10
```

Check `man ip-rule`.

Comment: Thanks! this solved the issue. Yet this does not clarify why using tun0 it is working and using it's IP address the packets are sent through wlan0 with the wrong address.


Could you please explain  what the second line does?

Comment: Never mind I figured out what the second line does. it basically sets a rule saying everything with source IP 10.8.0.52 shall use routing table 10.